# Typescript Typing Conflict

Tags: typescript, jsx

I am new to typescript. I use a third party package (mostly irrelevant which package, this is more of a general typescript question) as such:

```
export const GenerateTitle: FunctionComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
        <span>TeSTING&nbsp;&nbsp;<Badge>Soon</Badge></span>
    </div>
  )
};
export const Patient: FunctionComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
    ...
    <SubMenu icon={<GenerateTitle />} title={<GenerateTitle />} >
        <MenuItem>About</MenuItem>
    </SubMenu>
}
```

The code for the third party package shows the icon props and the title props having the same type

```
export type Props =  React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> & {
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  title?: React.ReactNode;
  ...
  onOpenChange?: (open: boolean) => void;
};

const SubMenu: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, Props> = (
  {
    icon,
    title,
    ...
    onOpenChange,
    ...rest
  },
  ref,
) => {

return (
    <li
      {...rest}
    >
      <div>
        {icon ? (
          <span className="pro-icon-wrapper">
            <span className="pro-icon">{icon}</span>
          </span>
        ) : null}
        {title ? <span className="pro-item-content">{title}</span> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 }
```

However, the `icon` prop renders the  component just fine while I get an error on the `title` prop stating:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(string & (boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null)) | undefined'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string & ReactPortal'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322
```

This is confusing me because it seems the typing and code to generate both the `icon` prop and the `title` prop are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your props extend `React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>`

The thing is that `<li>` elements already support a `title` attribute of type `string`. The browser uses this to provide little tooltips.

```html
<ul>
  <li title="tooltip!">hover over me for a second</li>
<ul>
```

So `React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>` has:

```
title?: string;
```

and then you are intersecting that with:

```
title?: React.ReactNode;
```

`ReactNode` is a union of a large number of things, one of which is a string. So you are basically doing:

```
(boolean | string | null | undefined | React.Fragment | ...) & string | undefined
```

The only valid intersection between both sides of the `&` is `string | undefined`. So the type is narrowed to something that is supported by all the intersected types.

---

So, if that's how this third party component works, that `title` must be a `string`, regardless of what type it says internally.

---

I think the authors intent was to support a JSX title by replacing the definition of the `title` prop with an entirely new one.

They probably meant to `Omit` that key from the `li` props entirely. Something like:

```
export type Props = Omit<React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, 'title'> & {
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  title?: React.ReactNode;
  //...
};
```

Comment: Thank so much, that makes sense, and that is what I suspected. I didn't understand typescript well enough to be certain. I think I need to fork the package to change the name of the prop... since it doesn't seem like there's a way to override the title type on`React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>` if you are extending it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah you don't want to change the built in HTML prop types. This seems like a bug in that code for sure. Also that `<li { ...rest }>` means that if you did pass JSX to `title`, then that jsx would get encoded on `<li title="somerenderedjsxhere">` which is pretty weird.

Comment: Actually I take that back, the title is filtered out above that line. My bad. The code is sound, but the types are not. See my update for a potential fix.